# Setting sort order on results for declared variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a specific order returned for the code below.   This is used to dynamically retrieve column headers.  But I can not get it to sort the way I want.  Any help is appreciated

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns+=N''+ColumnX
FROM
     (  
       SELECT  
       ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY FullName ASC) AS RowNum,
       N', p.'+QUOTENAME(ColumnX) as ColumnX
        FROM TableX
       GROUP BY ColumnX
  ) as x;
```

When I run the select in the () it orders that data correctly but when I run SELECT @Columns it is not pulling in the same order.

For example:

```
select in () returns rows in correct order 
 ,p.[Amy Smith],
 ,p.[Bob Jones]
 ,p.[Steve Jobs] 
 ,p.[Vince Neel]

SELECT @ columns returns 

 ,p.[Vince Neel],p.[Bob Jones],p.[Steve Jobs],p.[Amy Smith],
```

I have no idea how it is picking the order with it is pulled together.

Comment: You must always explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` clause if you care about the order in which the results are returned. Even if a query without an `ORDER BY` always appears to return the results in the order you want, there is no guarantee that it will do so in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `ORDER BY` clause. Else, the sequence might be "non-deterministic"

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns+=N''+ColumnX
FROM
     (  
       SELECT  
       ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY FullName ASC) AS RowNum,
       N', p.'+QUOTENAME(ColumnX) as ColumnX
        FROM TableX
       GROUP BY ColumnX
  ) as x
ORDER BY RowNum;   -- Added this
```

Comment: I prefer "non-deterministic" or "ill-defined" over "random". When you say random, some people will run their query three times, observe that they see the same result order all three times and decide that you're *wrong* about it being random.